# Time lap between mapM function calls

Tags: haskell

In my function:

```
mapM accessInternetFunc [a list of arguments]
```

The `accessinternetFunc` will access a web page with `simpleHttp` from `Http.conduit`. I find my program relatively slow and i suspect that it's because of the internet access time. So i wonder if the web server don't react immediately to my accessinternetFunc will my haskell program wait and then re call the function?
How much time will it wait before calling it again ?

To make myself clearer, if the list has 5 elements and after `map accessInternetFunc` applied to the first element, the web server wont react until 3 secs later, will my `map accessInternetFunc` wait ?

Comment: Just realized that probably this has something to do with internet connection session.. if so could anyone show a quick example how to get this working ?

Comment: 1) You are probably looking for `mapM` instead of `map`.  2) If your program is slow due to network latency then consider using `mapConcurrently` from the `async` package.  3) If you want to know if the TCP connection will be re-attempted then just make a test program (answser: yes it tries to reconnect with back-off).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Your point 2) is great! So mapConcurrent is like opening several tabs in a web browser at the same time right ?

Comment: Yes, that is an acceptable analogy.